# Automatically apply Database Migrations on build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set up a system, so when our Staging server builds, the "Update-Database" command is automatically applied.

The migrations are uploaded via the git pushes.

I've tried to put it as a build step in our CI, executing the console command: `dotnet ef update database` returning a headace since it does not seem to use the connection string form the config file and fails.

I also tried putting it as a `pre-build event command line` in the csproj, resulting it it hanging untill it eats up all the ram.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i was looking for at the end of the documentation>
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime

> Some apps may want to apply migrations at runtime during startup or
>   first run. Do this using the `Migrate()` method.
>
> This method builds on top of the IMigrator service, which can be used
>   for more advanced scenarios. Use `DbContext.GetService<IMigrator>()` to
>   access it.